# Symfony2: SonataAdmin. Если в форме выбран вариант, загрузить записи по связи

Tags: symfony2, symfony, entity, sonata

Здравствуйте,
На проекте используется sonata admin (symfony2). Допустим есть 2 entity, они связаны между собой как one-to-many. Мне нужно, чтобы в форме выводился выподающий список по 1-й entity, и после выбора ajax или еще как подгружались связанные записи по 2-й entity. 
Погуглил, документацию прошустрил, но вариантов не нашел.

P.s с фреймворком symfony2 не так давно знаком. Возможно это тривиальная задача решается достаточно быстро.

Все спасибо :)

Answer (score 1):

Решение оказалось на поверхности и в самой документации.
[В документации все есть](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#cookbook-form-events-submitted-data)

Answer (score 0):

Задача решается быстро, правда не знаю, как с сонатой (я её никогда не юзал)
Для многоразового использования надо создать отдельный тип поля для формы
[Symfony2 :: DependentEntity – зависимый выпадающий список](http://zeka.kiev.ua/symfony2-dependententity-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA/)

Answer (score 0):

если Вы планируете подгружать записи `ajax` то связь **one-to-many** тут не пригодится. Из `backend`-технологий Вам понадобится `API` которое будет возвращать набор по `id` `entity` 1.
Формирование выпадающего списка я бы доверил `frontend`, но возможно тут есть варианты решения